# Convert "True" to true JSON Python

Tags: python, json

Im reading json which has a boolean. When loading the file in Python with `json.load()`, I get `True` (I've read the specs).

```
{"XYZ": true}
```

As I understood I need to use `json.dumps()` to handle this. My dumps look like this.

```
convert = json.dumps({"true": True, "false": False})
```

And my load like this:

```
jdata = json.load(open(json_path))
```

When printing `jdata` I get:

```
{u'XYZ': True}
```

My question is, how do I convert the `True` to `true` after loading the json file? Later in my code I use the `jdata.iteritems()` to get all the keys and values.

If I write like this

```
jdata = json.load(open(json_path))
convert = json.dumps(jdata, {"true": True, "false": False})
```

it will print out:

```
{"XYZ": true}
```

But then I can't do

```
for key, value in convert.iteritems():
    #code
```

because I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
Here is the code

```
def ReadAndValidate(directory, json_path):

    jdata = json.load(open(json_path))
    path = findAllFiles(directory)

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
                for name in files:
                    with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as fle:
                        content = fle.read()
                    if name.endswith('.txt') and re.search(Wordboundry(key), content):
                        print "Name", key, "was found in", name, "\n"
                        writeToFile(value, content, name, key)
                   else:
                       print "Name", key, "was not found in", name"


def writeToFile(value, file_content, file, name):
    if type(value) is list:
        nrOfvalue = ' '.join([str(myValue) for myValue in value])
        nrOfvalue = "[ " + nrOfvalue + " ]"
        content = regFindName(name, nrOfvalue, file_content)
    else:
        content = regFindName(name, value, file_content)
    writeToFile(file, content)
```

I am using argumentparser where directory could be "C\Mydir\Dir1" and json_path "C:\MyDir\Dir1\myjson.json

myjson contains:

```
{"XYZ": true}
```

Function tries to find "XYZ" in a file. Leys say it finds it in the file "myFile.txt" which contains:

```
XYZ = false;
```

I wanna replace false with true if the name matches. The expected output in "myFile.txt" should be:

```
XYZ = true
```

The regFindName() finds the "name" (ex XYZ) by using regex++

Comment: `True` is true in python

Comment: What is `true` supposed to be? What's wrong with `True`?

Comment: Well when I later write to another file it has to be "true"

Comment: `json.dumps` takes a python object and outputs a string which is the json representation of that object. Especially it's of type string (or unicode in python2). You can't use `iteritems()` with that. You should use `jdata.iteritems()`.

Comment: @gants and it will be... `json.dumps({"true": True, "false": False})` -> `'{"true": true, "false": false}'`

Comment: If you just want to modify True to true, try command `sed 's/True/true/g'  input.csv`

Comment: @haifzhan python `True` is `true` in json so the file should not contain any `True`s (atleast no booleans). This rather seems to be an understanding problem. Still of course you are technically correct.

Comment: You reference code that isn't in your question. For example, "*it will print out ...*", but you don't have a `print` statement. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates your question. Please include its actual output and the output you expect to see.

Comment: Also please add a complete stacktrace if your programm throws any errors. It contains valuable debug information like linenumber.

Comment: @Robᵩ The actual output I want to see when it writes to my other file is: XYZ = true

Comment: What "other file" would that be? Don't answer here, just write a short complete program that demonstrates writing to the "other file", copy-paste that program into your question, and show us what result you get and what result you expect. For an explanation of how this technique helps you get excellent answers, see [mcve].

Comment: I have edited to post and given code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand the roles of `json.loads` and `json.dumps` (and their cousins, `json.load` and `json.dump`).

`json.dumps` (or `json.dump`) converts a Python object to a string (or file) which is formatted according to the JSON standard.

`json.loads` (or `json.load`) converts a string (or file) in JSON format to the corresponding Python object.

Consider this program:

```
import json

orig_python_object = { "XYZ": True }
json_string = json.dumps(orig_python_object)
new_python_object = json.loads(json_string)

assert orig_python_object == new_python_object
assert isinstance(orig_python_object, dict)
assert isinstance(new_python_object, dict)
assert isinstance(json_string, str)

for key, value in new_python_object.iteritems():
    pass
```

Of course one cannot `.iteritems()` the result of `.dumps()`. The result of `.dumps()` is a `str`, not a `dict`.

However, you can transmit that `str` (via file, socket, or carrier pigeon) to another program, and that other program can `.loads()` it to turn it back into a Python object.

Returning to your question:

> > how do I convert the "True" to true after loading the json file?

You do so by converting it back to JSON.

```
python_object = json.load(open("somefile.json"))
for k,v in python_object.iteritems():
    # some code
    pass
json_str = json.dumps(python_object)

assert 'true' in json_str
assert 'True' in str(python_object)
```

EDIT :

You've posted a larger part of your program in your question, which makes it more apparent where the problem lies. If I were you, I'd do one of two things:

1) I'd modify `writeToFile` like so:

```
def writeToFile(value, file_content, file, name):
    if type(value) is list:
        nrOfvalue = ' '.join([str(myValue) for myValue in value])
        nrOfvalue = "[ " + nrOfvalue + " ]"
        content = regFindName(name, nrOfvalue, file_content)
    elif isinstance(value, bool):
        content = regFindName(name, str(value).lower(), file_content)
    else:
        content = regFindName(name, value, file_content)
    writeToFile(file, content)
```

Or, 2) I'd modify `myjson.json` like so:

```
{"XYZ": "true"}
```

Comment: So simple, yet I was so far away with my thinking... thanks